# elastic search - update specific nested object

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I have hotel documents that each have rooms of nested type.

```
{
id: hotel_id,
   rooms: [
     {
        id: room_id_1,
        name: "room 1 name"
      },
      {
        id: room_id_2,
        name: "room 2 name"
      },
      ....
  ]
}
```

And I want to update only single field from a specific room. I am trying with the Update api, update the room with id 2 from the hotel document with id 1:

```
POST hotels/_update/1
{
  "script" : {
    "source" : "if(ctx._source.rooms.id == 2) { ctx._source.rooms.name = params.new_name }",
    "lang" : "painless",
    "params" : {
        "new_name" : "new room name"
    }  
  } 
}
```

I get this error "Illegal list shortcut value [id]" from ES.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to loop through `rooms` like this:

```
POST hotels/_update/1
{
  "script" : {
    "source" : "for (int i=0; i < ctx._source.rooms.length; i++) {if(ctx._source.rooms[i].id == 2) { ctx._source.rooms[i].name = params.new_name; break } }",
    "lang" : "painless",
    "params" : {
        "new_name" : "new room name"
    }  
  } 
}
```

Comment: Great, works, thank you! So obvious.. :) just for future reading the code inside the loop must make use of the "i" index of course.